# Assign an object before it is created (ObjC)

Tags: objective-c, oop, undeclared-identifier

I am just starting out with Obj-C. However since my background is Python I still struggle with few concepts and the syntax. I'm sure ObjC has mechanism to handle this (selectors?) but I still haven't got that far and I'm hoping to learn from you.

Consider this class:

```
@interface Drink : NSObject

@property NSString *drinkName;
@property NSDictionary *drinkIngredients;
@property (weak) Drink *similarDrinks;

@end
```

The property `similarDrinks` will link to other object of the same type (I was planning to do list of objects but decided to keep it simple, hence the plural).

My main file then contains this code:

```
Drink *margharita = [[Drink alloc] init];
    margharita.drinkName = @"Margharita";
    margharita.drinkIngredients = @{
                                    @"Fresh Lime Juice" : @22,
                                    @"Contreau" : @30,
                                    @"Blanco Tequila" : @45,
                                    };
```

Then there are more objects like this and finally I create `strawberryMargharita` object:

```
Drink *strawberryMargharita = [[Drink alloc] init];
strawberryMargharita.drinkName = @"Strawberry Margharita";
strawberryMargharita.drinkIngredients = @{
                                          @"Fresh Lime Juice" : @20,
                                          @"Contreau" : @30,
                                          @"Blanco Tequila" : @45,
                                          @"Strawberry Puree" : @40
                                          };
strawberryMargharita.similarDrinks = margharita;
```

Notice the property `strawberryMargharita.similarDrinks = margharita;` which works here because it was defined earlier. It would be nice if the object `margharita` could point to this object -> `margharita = strawberryMargharita.similarDrinks;`. I think this should be possible since ObjC compiler is dynamic right?

Also some people might point out that my data structure isn't perfectly suitable for this, maybe there is other and clever way to implement this but I'd like to know how to do it this way since I'd like to learn how to assign undeclared object. The whole Xcode project is on [Github](https://github.com/comatory/ironhack-favourite-recipe/blob/master/ironhack-favourite-recipe/main.m) with `main.m`, `drink.m` and `drink.h` files.

Comment: "since ObjC compiler is dynamic" – what do you mean by that? what sort of special "dynamism" does this need apart from another assingment (`margharita.similarDrinks = strawberryMargharita;`)?

Comment: You'd do that stuff in the overridden `[Drink init]` method, just like you would in the Python object constructor method (and pretty much every language).

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I tried that and I get `Use of undeclared identifier `strawberryMargharita`

Comment: @trojanfoe would you mind showing me the code to do this? thanks

Comment: @user3056783 obviously, you need to move the assignment to a place where `strawberryMargharita` already exists. For example, immediately after or before the other assignment.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant oh man I just had a 2 hour break and during that time I thought why I just didn't assign right at the end when all the objects are created... :) some obvious things are just not that obvious at the time.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that you need to derive a subclass for each specific drink, and initialize its name and ingredients in the subclass `init` method:

StarberryMargharitaDrink.h:

```
#import "Drink.h"

@interface StrawberryMargharitaDrink : Drink
@end
```

StrawberryMargharitaDrink.m:

```
#import "StawberryMargharitaDrink.h"

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        drinkName = @"Strawberry Margharita";
        drinkIngredients = @{
            @"Fresh Lime Juice" : @20,
            @"Contreau" : @30,
            @"Blanco Tequila" : @45,
            @"Strawberry Puree" : @40
        };
    }
    return self;
}
```

and then you can instantiate each drink explicitly:

```
Drink *drink = [StrawberryMargharitaDrink new];
```

However I am unsure how to implement the `similarDrink` functionality, other than to further subclass `Drink -> Margharita -> StrawberryMargharita`.

I would probably define an `enum DrinkClass` with an item for each similar drink and then assign that within the `init` method as well.

However, on the whole, it could get tedious defining all these types, and it might just be best to define all drinks in a dictionary and instantiate a `Drink` instance based on a leaf dictionary within this structure.  That would be easier to maintain and require fewer files to be created.

Comment: i went and had a look at it. it's not exactly what I had in mind but I've already figured out the solution. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning an object to a declared but not initialized variable – of the same type – is perfectly fine.

What you must not do is to add an object to a collection variable which is not initialized.

For example the code

```
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *similarDrinks;

...

[similarDrinks addObject:strawberryMargharita];
```

will crash or just do nothing, because the variable `similarDrinks` is `nil` at the moment `strawberryMargharita`is going to be added.